# Alert messages and error messages are not working in React Redux

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, react-redux

Here in action folder alert messages are not properly working. What is the error in the coding?

I have also attached my codesandbox link. For correct API it showing both alert messages and for error messages also its showing both errors: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-ride-y0i0pl?file=/src/actions/loginAction.js

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export const loginAction = {
    login,
};
function login(user) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        var data = {
            userName: user.userName,
            password: user.password,
        };
        axios
            .post('http://localhost:9091/login', data)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log("res", (res));
                
                dispatch(setUserLogin(res.data, false));
                alert("Login Sucessfully");

                localStorage.setItem("actNumber", JSON.stringify(res.data.accountNumbers))
                localStorage.setItem("Token", res.data.accessToken)
                localStorage.setItem("cifNumber", JSON.stringify(res.data.cifNumber).replace(/^"(.*)"$/, '$1'))
                window.location.pathname = "./register"

            })
            .catch(err => {

                dispatch(setUserLoginError(err, true));
                alert("Please Check UserName and Password");

            });

    };
}

export function setUserLogin(token, showError) {
    return {
        type: 'SET_LOGIN_SUCCESS',
         token: token,
        showError: showError,
        
    };
}

export function setUserLoginError(error, showError) {
    return {
        type: 'SET_LOGIN_ERROR',
        error: error,
        showError: showError,
    };
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? In the sandbox it does show an alert.

Comment: whenever i give an correct username and password in login page it showing alert messages as login successfull and it also showing error message like please check with username and password.